# How to resolve "Could not find match for name 'withXml'" output?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, maven-publish

In a Java library project of mine I have the following Gradle task defined

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

...

task createPom() {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId nexusGroupId
            artifactId nexusArtifactId
            version libVersion
            organization {
                name 'Example'
                url 'https://www.example.com'
            }
            withXml { asNode().appendNode('packaging', 'jar') }
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}
```

When I build the library the following is output to the console:

> Configure project :
>   Could not find match for name 'withXml'

I am using Gradle wrapper 4.10.3.

How can I resolve the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the builder for the project, you can only call the setters of the native [POM project model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html).

The method `withXml` is a method of Gradle's [MavenPom interface](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/maven/MavenPom.html) and can only be called after the MavenPom has been created:

```
task createPom() {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'Foo'
            artifactId 'Bar'
            version '1.0'
        }.withXml { 
            asNode().appendNode('packaging', 'jar')
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}
```